# Google AI Adventures code for simple Estimator for iris flower ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Sepal length'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

This is regarding an issue of the code which has been shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7oolm0jU8I&list=PLIivdWyY5sqJxnwJhe3etaK7utrBiPBQ2&index=3). I tried to run the code in TensorFlow (version 1.12 and 1.3) with python (version 3.7 and 3.6.4). But I get an error like below

`"ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Sepal length'".`

When I was running the code in TensorFlow version 1.12, I realized an additional warning/error which went into different code files to spit the mistake.

**#Code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

print (tf.__version__)

from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets import base

# Data files
IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set = base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
                                     features_dtype=np.float32,
                                     target_dtype=np.int)
test_set = base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TEST,
                                 features_dtype=np.float32,
                                 target_dtype=np.int)

print(training_set.data)

print(training_set.target)
```

**Traceback**

```
# 1.3.0

# ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-2-065d21e0a8b0> in <module>
#  13 training_set = base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
#  14                                          features_dtype=np.float32,
# ---> 15                                          target_dtype=np.int)
# 16 test_set = base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TEST,
# 17                                      features_dtype=np.float32,

# c:\users\sanjay\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\base.py in load_csv_with_header(filename, target_dtype, features_dtype, target_column)
# 46     data_file = csv.reader(csv_file)
# 47     header = next(data_file)
# ---> 48     n_samples = int(header[0])
# 49     n_features = int(header[1])
# 50     data = np.zeros((n_samples, n_features), dtype=features_dtype)

# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Sepal length'
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, the data file has to be formatted differently "sepal length" was my column header name. I had prepared it from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set

Instead of that using these files, the code works.

http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv, http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_test.csv﻿